# load the parent state not the child angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have list page along with filter(where list page is abstract and filter state is child state of list). On filter change location.search is updated but which causes both of them to reload controllers. Instead only list.

Following is the example

```
$stateProvider
            .state('list', {
                url: "/?search&type&content",
                abstract: true,  
                templateUrl: "list-template-path.html",
                controller: ListController,
                controllerAs: 'list'            
            })
            .state('list.filter', {
                url: "",
                templateUrl: "filter-template-path.html",
                controller: FilterController,
                controllerAs: 'filter'          
            })
```

Now on filter selection filter controller changes the parameter on url, which results into the loss of previous state on view part of the filters.

could you please provide the better solution for it?

Comment: If you want to load the parent state, don't use abstract in your parent state.

Comment: Then how can I load the child controller(filter) along with parent controller?